# Multiple convolutions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, convolution

I want to numerically calculate several convolutions like

[image]

where the `x`, `y`, `z`, `w` functions are given in the below code:

```
t = linspace(-100,100,10000);

x = t.*exp(-t.^2);
y = exp(-4*t.^2).*cos(t);
z = (t-2)/((t-2).^2+3^2);
w = exp(-3*t.^2).*exp(2i*t);

u = conv(conv(conv(x,y),z),w);

plot(t,u) % ??? - if we want to convolute N functions, what range should t span?
```

Is this the most efficient way to calculate and plot multiple convolutions? Is it generally better to numerically integrate the functions for each convolution?

**Edit:**

This is the plot of the real part of my convolution, `u` vs `t`:
[image]

whereas the method (using FFTs) suggested by a poster below gives me:

[image]

What causes this discrepancy?

Comment: Hi. Did you find a way to do it? And how do you calculate the correct values for the x-axis? Say, we wanted to calculate the convolution of 100 standard normal distributions with each input distribution sampled at $n$ points on the closed interval $[-a, a]$. The exact result is another normal pdf with $0$ mean and variance $10$ which I believe should span an interval $[-100a, 100a]$. Could you provide details of a Matlab code to achieve this? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the signal length is long, fft method would be better.

Below is an example.

```
t = linspace(-100,100,10000);

x = t.*exp(-t.^2);
y = exp(-4*t.^2).*cos(t);
z = (t-2)/((t-2).^2+3^2);
w = exp(-3*t.^2).*exp(2i*t);

L_x=fft(x);
L_y=fft(y);
L_z=fft(z);
L_w=fft(w);

L_u=L_x.*L_y.*L_z.*L_w; %convolution on frequency domain

u=ifft(L_u); 

figure(1)
plot(t,abs(u))
figure(2)
plot(t,real(u))
figure(3)
plot(t,imag(u))
```

Comment: This looks nice, but I'm not too keen in using Fourier transforms (my code will be a small part of a bigger programme where I'm not supposed to use FFTs).

Comment: Choice is up to you~ I think 'conv' function will well work, if signal is not long.

Comment: The only thing I changed in your code was `t = linspace(-100,100,1e6);`...

Comment: Did you check your code using 'conv' function with 1e6? I think first picture looks like using 10000 not 1e6.

Comment: Discrete convolution is sum of product of two discrete functions, so If you increase number of sampling point, the pick value will be also increased.

Comment: Could you please check your codes with the same line space condition?

Comment: I understand now. Yes you're right - there was an issue with the number of sampling points in `linspace`. It would be better to scale the result `u` by the sampling interval so we won't have this problem.

Comment: If I apply your approach to 4 standard normal distributions $N(0,1) sampled at $n=10^4$ point on $[-10,10]$, then when I plot the result it doesn't look like a $N(0,2)$. It seems like the range of $t$ values for the x-axis should be increased and reordered somehow. Could you provide a solution for this? Many thanks