# Solving convolutions in Matlab using `conv` or `fft`

Tags: matlab, fft, ifft

This is follow-up question to [my other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958662/multiple-convolutions-in-matlab) about performing multiple convolutions like

[image]

where the functions are defined in my code below.

I need to rescale the result of the convolution with respect to the number of time steps in the calculation, `N`.

```
N = 1000;
t = linspace(-10,10,N);

x = t.*exp(-t.^2);
y = exp(-4*t.^2).*cos(t);
z = (t-2)/((t-2).^2+3^2);
w = exp(-3*t.^2).*exp(2i*t);

% convolution
u = conv(conv(conv(x,y)/N,z)/N,w)/N;

% Fourier transform
L_x=fft(x)/N;
L_y=fft(y)/N;
L_z=fft(z)/N;
L_w=fft(w)/N;

L_u=L_x.*L_y.*L_z.*L_w; %convolution on frequency domain

v=ifft(L_u)*N; 

figure(1)
ax1 = subplot(2,1,1);
ax2 = subplot(2,1,2);

plot(ax1,1:length(u),real(u))
title(ax1,'conv')
hold off

plot(ax2,t,real(v))
title(ax2,'fft')
xlabel(ax2,'t')
```

- How do I scale the convolution correctly? (N.B. If I change to `N=1e5` timesteps, the y-values decrease).
- How do I ensure that the `conv` output spans the same time region as the `fft` output? Graph of real part of convolution below:

[image]

Comment: Your FFT method is performing [circular convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution) - you need to add appropriate padding to get linear convolution.

Comment: You mean zero-padding? What's the best way to do this for my arrays?

Comment: Read up on [frequency domain convolution](http://dspguide.com/ch9/3.htm). Note that this may not be your only problem, but it is a major problem that will need to be fixed.